# How do I use my custom ServiceStack authentication provider with Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack-bsd, servicestack-auth

I have implemented a custom `CredentialsAuthProvider` for my authentication and used it with the default in memory session storage.

Now I tried to change the session storage to Redis and added this to my `Configure()` method in the `AppHost`:

```cs
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => 
    new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));

container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => (ICacheClient)c
    .Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()
    .GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);
```

Now when I authenticate, I can see that a key with `urn:iauthsession:...` is added to my Redis server. But all routes with the `[Authenticate]` attribute give a `401 Unauthorized` error.

The `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider` is implemented like this:

```cs
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName != string.Empty && password != string.Empty)
        {
            // Database call ...
            var session = (CustomSession)authService.GetSession();
            session.ClientId = login.ClientId;
            // Fill session...
            authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

ServiceStack Version: 3.9.71

**EDIT :**

I tried to override the `CredentialsAuthProvider` `IsAuthorized` method but without success.

But I'm inheriting my session object from `AuthUserSession`, which also has a `IsAuthorized` method. When I return true from this method the Redis session does work with the `Authenticate` Attribute.

```cs
public class CustomSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    ...

    public override bool IsAuthorized(string provider)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to your issue, but you shouldn't be filling the session in the `TryAuthenticate` method. The preferred practise is in the `OnAuthenticated` method. [See here](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization). It seems there is a problem retrieving the session back from Redis in the `AuthenticationAttribute`. To debug this, I would start by removing the attribute from one of your action handlers and try adding `base.Request.GetSession()` within it, and see if your session is restored properly in your service.

Comment: @Scott I can retrieve the session in the action handler when i remove the `[Authenticate]` Attribute. So it seems this is a bug in the `AuthenticationAttribute`?

Comment: It's not a bug there is something wrong in your implementation. I think you need to set `session.UserAuthName` and `session.UserAuthId` unless your override `CredentialProviders` `IsAuthorized` method.

Comment: Thank you @Scott, but I didn't get it to work with the CredentialsProvider. See my updated question.

Comment: Just looking over your code. Remove `public ICacheClient cache { get; set; }` The ICacheClient is already setup in `Service` from which you inherit. You can just call `base.Cache`. Still looking to find other issues.

Comment: Your code looks functional. Are you getting errors with your new code?

Comment: no, i wasn't clear in my updated question. the code does work. and I can add/delete sessions from redis. also the [SessionAuth] Attributes works. It's just that it seems odd that I have to implement my own SessionAuth Attribute just to get redis working. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: You should post your updated code as the answer then and remove it from the question. You can just copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to get the `[Authenticate]` Attribute to work with Redis storage.

I had to write a custom `[SessionAuth]` Attribute

```cs
public class SessionAuthAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public ICacheClient cache { get; set; }
    public string HtmlRedirect { get; set; }

    public SessionAuthAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        string sessionId = req.GetSessionId();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
        {
            HandleNoSession(req, res);

        }
        else
        {
            var session = cache.Get<CustomSession>("urn:iauthsession:" + sessionId);
            if (session == null || !session.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                HandleNoSession(req, res);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleNoSession(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res)
    {

        if (req.ResponseContentType.MatchesContentType(MimeTypes.Html))
        {

            res.RedirectToUrl(HtmlRedirect);
            res.End();

        }
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        res.Write("not authorized");
        res.Close();
    }
}
```

In my AppHost Configure() method I just register the SessionFeature and the IRedisClientsManager/ICacheClient:

```cs
Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());

container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));

container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => (ICacheClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()
        .GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);
```

The CustomSession class inherits from AuthUserSession:

```cs
public class CustomSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And I have a normal service route on /login/auth for the authentication part and a /login/logout route to remove the session:

```cs
public class LoginService : Service
{
    public ICacheClient cache { get; set; }

    public object Post(AuthRequest request)
    {
        string userName = request.UserName;
        string password = request.Password;

        // check login allowed

        if (IsAllowed)
        {

            var session = SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession<CustomSession>(cache);

            session.ClientId = login.ClientId;
            ...
            session.IsAuthenticated = true;
            session.Id = SessionFeature.GetSessionId();

            this.SaveSession(session, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30 * 60));


            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    [SessionAuth]
    public object Any(LogoutRequest request)
    {
        this.RemoveSession();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

I'm still interested in a solution that works with the normal `[Authenticate]` Attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The `Authenticate` attribute calls the `IsAuthorized` of the `AuthUserSession` class.
In my case to make it work with the Redis cache client, I've done the following

```
public override bool IsAuthorized(string provider)
{
    string sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(this.Id);
    ICacheClient cacheClient = AppHostBase.Resolve<ICacheClient>();

    CustomUserSession session = cacheClient.Get<CustomUserSession>(sessionKey);

    if (session == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return session.IsAuthenticated;
}
```